# Select the parent of an element which has a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I built up a navigation bar which has the following sort of markup:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="blah.html">S</a></li>
    <li><a href="blah1.html">S1</a></li>
    <li><a href="blah2.html">S2</a></li>
    <li><a href="blah3.html">S3</a></li>
</ul>
```

In one my events here, I have the access to the `a` element on which the user clicked.

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'li a', function(){
var clickedLink = $(this);
var prevActiveLI = ?
var currentClickedAnchorsParentLI = ?
});
```

There are two things I want to get here for my purpose. The previous `li` tag which has the `active` class applied and secondly, the `li` tag for the `a` which has just been clicked. How can that be accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'li a', function(){
    var clickedLink = $(this);
    var prevActiveLI = $('.active', $clickedLink.closest('.nav'));
    var currentClickedAnchorsParentLI = $clickedLink.closest('li');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'li a', function(){
  var clickedLink = $(this);
  var prevActiveLI = clickedLink.closest('ul.nav').find('li.active');
  var currentClickedAnchorsParentLI = clickedLink.parent();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $prevLi,
$currentLi
;

$('.nav').on('click', 'li a', function(){
 var clickedLink = $(this);
 if($currentLi) {
  $prevLi = $currentLi;
 }
 $currentLi = clickedLink.parent();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'li a', function(){
  var clickedLink = $(this);

  var currentClickedAnchorsParentLI = clickedLink.parent();

  if(!currentClickedAnchorsParentLI.hasClass("active"))
    var prevActiveLI = currentClickedAnchorsParentLI.siblings(".active").first();
  //else
    //
});
```