# Find an element with a certain class and add a class to the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am customizing a CMS. I have the ability to add CSS and JavaScript. I wish to add a CSS class specification to a specific entry displayed in a list. In the example below where there is a class of `ifrep`. I would like to add the class of `ifreprow` to the div (above/outside/parent?). The div id is not predictable so I can't address that div with `id="com_locator_entry_36"`. I hope this makes sense. I know the ready and `addclass` aspects of the JavaScript/jQuery but have no idea how to find that class and add another class to that particular div.

```
<div id="mm_results_wrapper" class="com_locator_results_wrapper collapse_list_show combined" style="">
    <div class="com_locator_entry row0 mm_" rel="of_0" id="com_locator_entry_36">
        <div class="com_locator_address">
            <span class="line_item ifrep">Sales Contact</span>
            <br>
            <strong>
                <h2 class="com_locator_title" itemprop="name">
                    Billy Schwartz
                    <a class="collapse_list_reveal" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="load_detail_page(36);">Billy Schwartz</a>      
                </h2>
            </strong> 
            <br>
            <span itemprop="telephone" class="line_item phone">303-303-0303</span>
            <br>
            <span class="line_item email">
                <a data-conversion="Email-Mailto" href="mailto:billys@somewhere.com" target="_blank">Email</a>
            </span>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this help: $('#mm_results_wrapper').find('.ifrep').closest('div.com_locator_entry').addclass('ifreprow');

Comment: @COBOL-love you might want to reword the title. It is a pretty generalized question. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's `addClass()`, not `addclass()`, but other than that @Mojtaba has your answer.

Comment: @DanielBeck. You are right. It's a typo

Comment: Thank you all very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select the parent of an element which has a certain class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357771/select-the-parent-of-an-element-which-has-a-certain-class)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about what you really ask for, but if I understand well you want something like this:

```
$(".ifrep").parent().addClass("ifreprow");
```

Comment: Your welcome @COBOL-love. Be sure to accept my answer if it helped you, so that others can find it easily in the future :)